# Javascript - Get checkbox values from a form and get a random result

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, random

I have a form that allows multiple checkbox. I want to get a random value of all **checked items** when the "Generate" button is pressed.

On the one hand I have the form:

```
<FORM NAME="testform">
<INPUT CLASS="cities" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="mex" Value="mex"checked="checked">México<BR>
<p><INPUT CLASS="cities" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="ita" Value="ita">Italy<BR>
<p><INPUT CLASS="cities" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="usa" Value="usa">United State of America<BR>
<p><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Generate" 
onClick="testButton"><BR>
</FORM>
```

But I am a novice in JavaScript and I need help building this exercise.

By the other hand I have no idea how to get the form values. These are the random elements of each checkbox.

```
var mex=["mexico-df.html","veracruz.html","acapulco.html"]
var ita=["roma.html","milan.html","venecia.html"]
var usa=["los-angeles.html","new-york.html","washington.html"]
```

I want that if something check México and USA, for example, the result should be only one random value between those included in the above variables.

I do not know exactly how to get the checked values from the form and how to pick a random value from only selected items.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Sorry if my English is not so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand you, you are looking for something like this:

```
function testButton() {
    var mex=["mexico-df.html","veracruz.html","acapulco.html"];
    var ita=["roma.html","milan.html","venecia.html"];
    var usa=["los-angeles.html","new-york.html","washington.html"];

    var allOptions = [];

    var isMexChecked = document.getElementsByName("mex")[0].checked;
    if (isMexChecked) {
        allOptions = allOptions.concat(mex);
    }

    var isItaChecked = document.getElementsByName("ita")[0].checked;
    if (isItaChecked) {
        allOptions = allOptions.concat(ita);
    }

    var isUsaChecked = document.getElementsByName("usa")[0].checked;
    if (isUsaChecked) {
        allOptions = allOptions.concat(usa);
    }

    if (allOptions.length > 0) {
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * allOptions.length));
        console.log(allOptions[random]);
        return allOptions[random];
    }
}
```

Just make sure you attach the JS handler correclty in the form:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Generate" 
onClick="testButton()">
```

Later on if you have more options for countries, you might want to make things more concise:

```
var checkBoxNameToValuesMap = {
    "mex" : mex,
    "ita" : ita,
    "usa" : usa
};

for (var checkBoxName in checkBoxNameToValuesMap) {
    if (document.getElementsByName(checkBoxName)[0].checked) {
        allOptions = allOptions.concat(checkBoxNameToValuesMap[checkBoxName]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much **todor.hr**. I tried to place the script but when I press the button shows nothing.

Comment: It just prints to the JS console. Alternatively if you want to see the value change `console.log()` with `alert(allOptions[random])`